# How to make javascript table into a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

As part of my work, I am trying to re-design our reporting software and make the tables look consistent. The site consists of many pages, pretty much all containing a table.

There seem to be two different types of table. The [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeRDi.png) is a HTML datatable, using the following code to make the table look good:

```
<table style="width:100%;clear:left;" id="orderlist">
    bla bla bla
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#orderlist').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "paging": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "sDom": '<"H"pf>t<"F"lirp>',
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": language.fetching_data,
        "sSearch": language.search,
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    language.page_nav_first,
            "sLast":     language.page_nav_last,
            "sNext":     language.page_nav_next,
            "sPrevious": language.page_nav_prev
        },
        "sEmptyTable": "<p>" + language.no_data_table + "</p>",
        "sInfo":          language.datatable_show_entries,
        "sInfoEmpty":   language.datatable_empty_entries
    }
});
```

});

The second table type seems to be created through javascript. When I add the script from the first table below the script to make this table, it does not do anything. You can see the code from the second table [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFVcA.png). Can anyone tell me how I can combine the two?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second  table doesn't have `id` attribute and doesn't have proper structure.

jQuery DataTables requires the table to have `thead` and `tbody` elements, for example:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML) for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much - that is really helpful! I will work on adding these elements and hopefully it will work! I take it I can just add the script from the first table below the script that creates the second table?